# How to pass arguments in function when the function has void* parameter?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I have to implement enqueue operation in a `queue`. In a node structure the `datatype` for `dataPtr` is `void*`. 
This is my code but while calling this function how shall I pass the arguments?

```
typedef struct node
{
void* dataptr;
 struct node* next;
 } QUEUE_NODE;

typedef struct
{
    QUEUE_NODE* front;
    QUEUE_NODE* rear;
    int count;
}QUEUE;

//createqueue
QUEUE* createQueue(void)
{
    QUEUE* queue;
    queue = (QUEUE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE));
    if (queue)
    {
        queue->front = NULL;
        queue->rear = NULL;
        queue->count = 0;
    }
    return queue;
}
//Enqueue
bool enqueue(QUEUE* queue, void* itemptr)
{
    QUEUE_NODE* newptr;
    if (!(newptr = (QUEUE_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE))))
        return false;
    newptr->dataptr = itemptr;
    newptr->next = NULL;
    if (queue->count == 0)
        queue->front = newptr;
    else
        queue->rear->next = newptr;
    (queue->count)++;
    queue->rear = newptr;
    printf("inserted value is%d\n", newptr->dataptr);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `void *` pointer of the queue means it can store (a pointer to) any type of data; the queue doesn't care what you store in it.

So you can call the enqeue function just with a pointer to your data type. There should be no need to cast it to `(void *)`.

Comment: Similarly there is no need to cast the `void*` pointer returned by `malloc`, it can be assigned to any pointer type.